# Why the tee command output something very strange when I capture the result from VIM?

Tags: command-line, vim, tee

I can recognise the welcome message, like:
`VIM - Vi IMproved[9;35Hversion 7.3[10;29Hby Bram Moolenaar et al.[11;19HVim is open source and freely distributable[13;26HBecome a registered Vim user![14;18Htype  :help register[34m<Enter>[m   for information [16;18Htype  :q[34m<Enter>[m               to exit         [17;18Htype  :help[34m<Enter>[m  or  [34m<F1>[m  for on-line help[18;18Htype  :help version7[34m<Enter>[m   for version info[1;1H[?12l[?25h[?25l[24;1H`

and some cmd `1m-- INSERT --[1;1H[?12l[?25h[?25l[mT[7;32H[94m`, But the message I type is totally can't readable. Here is the thing I capture using this cmd:

`vim | tee -a /Users/User/Desktop/vim.txt`

[image]

Comment: What in all hell are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are wondering what you captured:

you captured the escape sequences vim uses to control the output to your terminal.

You seem to be viewing vim.txt with vim.  Use less instead:

```
less /Users/User/Desktop/vim.txt
```

Then you should see that each square-bracket "[" is preceded by the escape character (ESC).

For more info about what you are seeing- search for "terminfo" and "ncurses".